# How can I remove my camera rotation "snapping"?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I clamp my x-axis and y-axis rotations when climbing a ladder. The bool below is called from another script which uses OnTriggerEnter.

So basically when I enter the trigger and the below if statement becomes true, everything is fine. However, when I first enter the trigger, my rotation snaps to Global Rotation (0,0,0).  When I exit the trigger, the rotation snaps again to whatever my last rotation was while in the trigger.

```
if (climbing.climbing)
{
            
    float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity;
    float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity;
            
    xRotation -= mouseY;
    yRotation += mouseX;

    xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);
    yRotation = Mathf.Clamp(yRotation, -35f, 35f);

    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(xRotation, yRotation, 0f); 
    player.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
}
```

The code above is run inside Update() of the MouseCamera script, which is attached to my Camera. I'm also not sure if it matters or not, but my Player object is not attached to my Camera. My Camera is on its own and I use an offset to make it follow the Player around.

I also tried replacing my `transform.eulerAngles` + `transform.rotate` lines to: `transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(yRotation, Vector3.up) * Quaternion.AngleAxis(xRotation, Vector3.right);` but there was no change.

Comment: Can you give a GIF?

Comment: https://giphy.com/gifs/TFT0ihKHyA0DLSPl5t I have a gif here. As you can see, no matter what position the ladder is in (I have one at (0,0,0) rotation, another at (0,90,0), as you can see, when I first enter the ladder trigger, my camera snaps. When I exit, it also snaps drastically

Comment: How do you make the player climb, do you add it to another game object as a child?

Comment: Can you show us the rest of your code(s) affecting the player rotation etc .. it sounds like while you aren't climbing you are using different fields that only get updated while not climbing => snaps back to previously stored rotation before the climb

Comment: And accordingly also `when I first enter the trigger, my rotation snaps to Global Rotation (0,0,0)` -> Yes, because up until that moment you never updated `xRotation` and `yRotation` so the initial rotation you apply will be `transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0f);`

Comment: The bounty attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Comment: @derHugo I'm not sure where I'm supposed to post my code etc, all I'm seeing across this post is downvotes and something about plagiarizing. I have updated my code drastically, and all I have is one issue to do with Quaternion.RotateTowards

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue you are facing is related to the order in which the rotations are applied and how the different rotations are being handled. When clamping the rotations, there might be some differences between the local and global rotations, causing unexpected behavior.

To fix this, you can change the code to handle the rotations separately and avoid conflicts between global and local rotations.

```
if (climbing.climbing)
{
    float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity;
    float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity;
    
    // Apply rotation to the camera around its local axes
    xRotation -= mouseY;
    yRotation += mouseX;

    // Clamp the rotations locally
    xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);
    yRotation = Mathf.Clamp(yRotation, -35f, 35f);

    // Apply the local rotations
    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f); // Only rotate around local X-axis
    player.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX); // Rotate the player around global Y-axis
}
```

Also, make sure to double-check the setup of the camera, player, and any other scripts that may interact with rotations to ensure there are no conflicting rotations or adjustments that might be affecting the behavior.

Comment: If I wanted to clamp my left - right movement, would I just replace the xRotation inside the Quaternion.Euler to yRotation?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If you want to clamp the left-right movement, you would replace the xRotation inside the Quaternion.Euler with yRotation. This will ensure that the camera's left-right movement (rotation around the global Y-axis) is clamped to the specified range.

Comment: Yeah that's been my issue even from before. Despite replacing it with yRotation, the left and right movement still does not clamp, but vertical clamp remains functional. I stripped away other code to make sure nothing was interfering, but that has not helped, I am not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: do you know why the issue is still here? I've spent the last few hours changing a lot of values/variables around but the script is not recognizing that the yRotation clamp even exists.

Comment: `player.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);`  a) this doesn't apply any clamping at all .. and b) this rotates in **local** space, not around the global Y-axis (for this you would have to pass in `Space.World` as second parameter)

Answer (score 0):

**The problem** lies in the fact that you dont take relative orientation into account. Just clamping by arbitrary degrees will limit the player in global rotation but that is not connected to the ladder.

*(The following example is simplified to only take horizontal view rotation into account)*

I created a simple test setup to illustrate the issue:

1. Create Cube, name it TestPlayer
2. Add Rigidbody, turn off gravity
3. Create Cube, name it TestLadder
4. Increase Collider size xyz to 2

Add following script to TestPlayer:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    float yRotation;
    float minRot=-35;
    float maxRot=35;
    
    void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * 1;

        yRotation += mouseX;

        yRotation = Mathf.Clamp(yRotation, minRot, maxRot);

        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0f, yRotation, 0f);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        minRot = other.transform.eulerAngles.y-35f;
        maxRot = other.transform.eulerAngles.y+35f;
    }
}
```

5. Seperate TestPlayer and TestLadder and Play

[image]

6. Move mouse and see how Testplayer rotation is clamped globally to arbitrary 35° offset. (See blue forward arrow)
7. Drag TestPlayer into collider of TestLadder, move mouse and see how the Testplayer rotation gets clamped relatively to the TestLadder.  (See blue forward arrow)

[image]

The suggested code solution is far from a usable solution but should illustrate the problem and provide enough insight to redesign what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I added to your code and adjusted it based on my project and the clamp works but there is a problem. I use two mouse movements codes inside an if and else statement. So if my trigger bool = true, do your clamp movement. Else, do normal movement. And because right as the trigger turns true/false, the mouse movement changes, there is gimbal lock/rotation snap still. https://pastebin.com/t8Mv74Dr Is there any way I can adjust my DoNonClampedRotation so that when the game transitions from ClampedMovement to nonClampedRotation, there's no rotation snap?

Comment: I am confused because the code you provided still has a clamp in the nonClampedRotation? 
Logically speaking, of course there will be snapping. If the player is not facing the ladder and walks into the ladder trigger, thus activating the clamping, the player gets snapped into the clamped rotation. If that is not what it should do, more logic has to be added.
On the other hand. If the player leaves the restricted movement, there should be no snapping, since lifting restrictions dont force any movement. If snapping happens when lifting restrictions, there is unwanted rotation setting by code.

Comment: At this point, i find it too hard to predict your Unity setup without any further information on your code. I am still suggesting to apply and lift restictions when triggered inside your movement code, not duplicating logic. The code you gave spins my setup weirdly and is not replicable without changes.

Answer (score -3):

The issue you're experiencing seems to be due to the fact that you're setting the rotation directly using transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(xRotation, yRotation, 0f);. This will set the rotation to the specified values, which are initially zero.

When you enter the trigger, xRotation and yRotation are zero (unless you've set them elsewhere), so the rotation is set to (0, 0, 0). When you exit the trigger, xRotation and yRotation are set to the last values they had while in the trigger, so the rotation snaps to those values.

To fix this, you need to initialize xRotation and yRotation to match the current rotation when you enter the trigger. This way, the rotation won't snap to (0, 0, 0) when you enter the trigger. You can do this by adding the following code to your OnTriggerEnter method:

```
    if (!climbing.climbing)
{
    // Convert the current rotation from Quaternion to Euler angles
    Vector3 currentRotation = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;

    // Initialize xRotation and yRotation to match the current rotation
    xRotation = currentRotation.x;
    yRotation = currentRotation.y;
}
```

This will ensure that xRotation and yRotation match the current rotation when you start climbing, so the rotation won't snap to (0, 0, 0).

Similarly, when you exit the trigger, you should save the current rotation so that it can be restored later. You can do this by adding similar code to your OnTriggerExit method:

```
    if (climbing.climbing)
{
    // Convert the current rotation from Quaternion to Euler angles
    Vector3 currentRotation = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;

    // Save the current rotation
    xRotation = currentRotation.x;
    yRotation = currentRotation.y;
}
```

This will ensure that the rotation doesn't snap when you stop climbing. Instead, it will smoothly transition from the climbing rotation to the normal rotation.

Hope this helps!

-$

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT